# Return just the item of a list if len(list) == 1

Tags: python

I have a list with possibly several items (tuples) that I need to return.  But what about, in the case that I only get one item in my list, I would like to return the item itself and not a list with only one item.  How could this be done?

This is my code:

```
def strength(self):
    values = []
    max_v = 0
    my_list = []
    for i in inspect.getmembers(self):
        if not i[0].startswith('_'):
            if not inspect.ismethod(i[1]): 
                if "name" in i:
                    continue
                values.append(i[1])
                my_list.append(i)
                max_v = max(values)
    result = [tup_item for tup_item in my_list  if tup_item[1] == max_v]
    result.sort(reverse=True)
    if len(result) > 1:               
        return tuple(result)
    else:  # in case len(result) == 1
        return result  # this is where i get a list with only one item but
                       # i would like to get just the tuple itself
```

Comment: Poor idea, leave the list in place. If your caller has to be prepared to receive a list anyway, handling a single element as a special case would only complicate the code.

Comment: `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.` That said, I'm not sure why there is a question. It seems that, at the line of code, `return result`, you are confused as to how to, given a list with one item in it, get (and return) the item instead? Well - do you know how to get the item at a given index? If a list contains exactly one item, do you know what the index of that item is? Can you see how to put those two things together?

Answer (score 3):

If your list only has one item, it's usually at the 0th index. Just `return result[0]`. I would not recommend it though, since you will have to differentiate between lists and tuples from wherever you're calling that function.

Comment: "If your list only has one item, it's usually at the 0th index" ...always, in fact :)